# Object becomes transparent when camera goes trough

Tags: camera

i'm a beginner on blender and i just got this problem, i'm making a camera animation and when i approach an object it becomes transparent although the camera doesn't touch the object, do anyone have any fix?

Answer (score 2):

Camera has a "clipping distance" any objects outside this interval clipped:

[image]

You can modify this values, but keep in mind, that a not huge interval helps Blender avoid [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting#:%7E:text=Z%2Dfighting%2C%20also%20called%20stitching,which%20keeps%20track%20of%20depth.)